# Type ' | undefined' is not assignable to type '' when using FIND from array object

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to find an element from one array and assign it into another array object.

But its saying

Type 'ClosureSummary | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ClosureSummary'

```
var dt = $('#tbl_summary').DataTable();
let ids:string[]=[];
dt.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes().each(function(item,index){
  ids.push(item.id)

});
console.info(ids);
this.liveBoundSummary.forEach(element=>{
  let pcode:string=element.ProjectCode;
  if(ids.includes(pcode)){
    let csItem:any;
    element=this.clSummary.find(x=>x.ProjectCode==pcode);

  }
});
```

Here when I try to assign the values **found** from clSummary array into liveBoundSummary element its showing the undefined error.

Both clSummary and liveBoundSumary are of same type ClosureSummary[]

How to resolve that

Answer (score 2):

I am able to fix it using **non-null assertion operator (!)**, so I am sharing the same for those who faces the same issue

So when assigning I made it like this

```
element=this.clSummary.find(x=>x.ProjectCode==pcode)!;
```

Which solved the issue